# Do I need to setup aws_autoscaling_group in fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I build my containers with fargate and terraform.

If I want to scale when the cpu or the memory not enough, do I need to setup `aws_autoscaling_group` in terraform? or aws can automatic raise up another containers?

Comment: You need to tell AWS / terraform that you want autoscaling to take place, yes. Fargate does not do that fully automatically. See e.g. https://github.com/strvcom/terraform-aws-fargate/blob/0.17.0/main.tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without setting this AWS has no way of knowing that the service should autoscale or which conditions it should scale on.

Instead it will just use the `desired_count` value instead (as a static value).

If you create the auto scaling resource this will replace this value.